# How to host a Java EE website on GlassFish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I have already deployed my web application on GlassFish at `http://localhost:8080/Elibrary/`.

So how can I configure my server to make "Elibrary" accessible from the Internet?

I know that in ASP we can use IIS to alias the from domain.

Could someone please let me know or point me to some documentation?

Comment: if you try 'http://<your_ip>:8080/Elibrary' does it not work? How is your network configured, i mean are you using wireless router/switch?

Comment: It not work , i using  router, port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you are hosting in your network, then you have to get IP of the machine which is running your app i.e. is your local ip inside ur network. To get your ip, run `ifconfig` on mac/unix/linux and `ipconfig` on windows.
- Then go to your router settings. Generally every router has specific ip to access settings from browser like belkin has 'http://192.168.2.1'.
- In your router settings you have to look for 'virtual servers', 'port forwarding' etc. The actual concept is port forwarding but different routers say it differently in the settings. These settings should be in firewall or security sections.
- Once you found the settings, there you will have to tell the inbound port range and map it to the local ip (which we have above) and the outbound port range. It is saying that when ever a request comes on the router on the inbound port range then forward that request to local ip and port range. In your case, the port range will be  to  (for both inbound and outbound). Note that some routers dont have range for ports instead only have one port per entry, so you just have to put .

NOTE: To get the IP for settings of your router, try this [site](http://www.routeripaddress.com/).

I hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: Hi is it possible to access the application deployed on glassfish if my computer is connecting to the internet using the Android's Portable Wi-Fi hotspot? This question has given me so much trouble I have even posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935355/how-to-access-server-from-another-computer-if-the-server-machine-is-exposed-to-t

Answer (score 1):

Nginx or Apache will work will in that scenario, processing virtual hosts and forwarding to an external application. Example for nginx.

Put this in place of the server section in an existing config file, unless using Debian/Ubuntu or other system where the server configurations are split into their own files.

```
server {
    listen ip:80;
    server_name virtualhostname.tld;

    location "/" {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    };
};
```

Now http://virtualhostname.tld/Elibrary will work to access your application.

You can add rewiriting to get rid of Elibrary, and you find Apache equivalents of this online.